# C++ unordered_map with custom hash issues

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I am trying to write a custom hash function for use in an unordered_map. I am able to insert items and iterate through them, but cannot lookup items using the at(), find() or operator[] functions.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define JHASH_GOLDEN_RATIO  0x9e3779b9

using namespace std;

#define __jhash_mix(a, b, c) \
{ \
  a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>13); \
  b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<8); \
  c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>13); \
  a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>12);  \
  b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<16); \
  c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>5); \
  a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>3);  \
  b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<10); \
  c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>15); \
}

uint32_t
jhash_3words (uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t initval)
{
  a += JHASH_GOLDEN_RATIO;
  b += JHASH_GOLDEN_RATIO;
  c += initval;

  __jhash_mix (a, b, c);

  return c;
}

size_t jenkins_hash(const uint32_t &num){
    return (size_t) jhash_3words (num, 0, 0, rand());
}

int main(){

    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, char, std::function<decltype(jenkins_hash)>> ids(0, jenkins_hash );

        ids[(uint32_t) 42341] = 'g';
        ids[(uint32_t) 2232] = 'b';
        ids[(uint32_t) 7556] = 'q';

    for ( auto it = ids.begin(); it != ids.end(); ++it ){
        std::cout << "Element " << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << ids.size() << std::endl;

    printf("%c\n", ids.find(7556)->second);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the above code:

```
Element 2232 b
Element 7556 q
Element 42341 g
3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My questions are...

- Why is this producing a segfault?
- Why do at() and operator[] simply return nothing, whereas find()
  segfaults?

Any ideas?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but please avoid symbols with two leading underscores (like `__jhash_mix`) as those are reserved for "the implementation" (compiler and standard library). See [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for information.

Comment: id `find` in `ids.find(7556)->second` returns no iterator and same time you trying to access its `second`, this will trigger seg fault

Comment: Your hash is not deterministic, please try to understand what hashing means and what `unordered_map` is doing before trying to plug in a custom hash

Comment: On another unrelated note, please avoid C-style casting in C++ as well. If you need to do it then you most likely are doing something wrong.

Comment: As for your problem, read the comment by @PasserBy, and try to understand what's meant by "not deterministic". As a hint: What do you think the `rand` function does? How could two identical keys generate the same hash if you have a random component mixed into the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
size_t jenkins_hash(const uint32_t &num){
    return (size_t) jhash_3words (num, 0, 0, rand());
}
```

Since your hash function includes a random element, the two times `7556` is hashed will yield different hashed values. This means that the lookup done by `find` fails to locate anything and actually returns `ids.end()`, which you should not dereference.

Here's how you should be using `find()`:

```
auto found = ids.find(7556);
if(found != ids.end()) {
  printf("%c\n", found->second);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that makes total sense. Changed to a constant and it worked perfectly. Thanks!